# What should be the type of string for regex: '\S+?@\S+'

Tags: python, regex

Let us say given string is:
From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2008

According to me answer should be:  d@uct.ac.za
because Number of non-whitespace characters should be lazy greedy(as few as possible) hence.
But python says: stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za

```
import re
hand = open('textfile.txt')
for line in hand:
    line=line.rstrip()
    x=re.findall('\S+@\S+',lin)
    if x:
      print x
```

and textfile.txt is:

```
From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2008
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Also post your attempt or code.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please have a look on [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and on [how do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to increase the likelihood of getting your question answered.

Comment: People keep forgetting that a regex engine parses the input string from left to right and each item that is not greedily quantified matches the leftmost occurrence. Lazy and greedy do not match the shortest or longest substrings, it is just a figure of speech to simplify explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say:

> Number of non-whitespace characters should be lazy greedy(as few as possible) hence.

In your case it implies it should be either **one or zero**.

Hence making non-whitespace character `optional` using `?` quantifier will do the job.

Try with `\S?@\S+`

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XxNNYV/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

If you just want one character before `@`, you could use :

```
'\S@\S+'
```

Non-greedy doesn't mean that the regex will try to find the shortest substring by varying the start index. It just means that if there's a substring which starts at index 0 and matches the regex, the engine will stop as soon as possible.

Comment: In case if there is no character before `@` it will fail. I think making it optional is better.

Comment: @Rahul: OP seems to be looking for email addresses. There should be a character before `@`.

Comment: @Rahul I don't understand the need to only match one character, though.

Comment: Me too. That's for OP to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the answer to this one. Bit late on the trend, but here it goes.

Let's reference Eric's statement first:
Non-greedy ... just means that if there's a substring which starts at index 0 and matches the regex, the engine will stop as soon as possible.

Okay fellas. So the engine starts at index 0. It reads stephen.marquard, it still hasn't reached @ yet so it goes on, but there isn't anything yet that deems its selection wrong so it keeps it in the memory.

It reaches the @ sign. Great. The \S+? will not impact before @ but will impact after @ because the engine reads from left to right. When it reaches u in @uct, it has satisfied requirements, so it stops there. While reading through stephen.marquard@ it still hasn't.

Answer (score 0):

it will extract the following " stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za "
because the ? sign works only after the @ but not before it

Answer (score -1):

I have your same question and it's not yet answered.
The non greedy '?' works for after the '@' but not for before it. I have no explanation for it.

You can try `[^ ]@[^ ]+` for the required/expected answer.